# Ruby on Rails Twitter trends - TypeError = can't convert string into integer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter

I'm getting a really strange error message in my app. In my controller I have:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'
class NoticiasController < ApplicationController
  def index
    url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1/trends/daily.json'
    buffer = open(url, "UserAgent" => "Ruby-Wget").read
    # convert JSON data into a hash
    @result = JSON.parse(buffer)
    end
  end
```

and in the view I have

```
<div>
  <% for news in @result['trends'] %> 
  <p><%= news['name'] %></p>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

but I get "TypeError: can't convert String into Integer".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: on which line do you get the error?

Comment: @Joe Doyle: Thanks for helping with the [cleanup](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012), but isn't this a legitimate use of [tag:trends]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`results['trends']` is a map of timestamp => [trends].

You need to pick a trend date, then iterate over the array of trends.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :011 > result['trends'].keys.each { |k| puts k }
2011-11-13 17:00
2011-11-13 19:00
2011-11-13 14:00
2011-11-13 16:00
2011-11-13 18:00
2011-11-13 15:00
# etc.

ruby-1.9.2-p290 :022 > result['trends']["2011-11-13 17:00"].each { |t| p t["name"] }; nil
"#myweddingsong"
"#mydivorcesong"
"#ThingsPeopleShouldntDo"
"GOOD LUCK 1D"
# etc.
```

For example, to get the names of the latest trends:

```
> ts = result['trends'].keys.sort.last
"2011-11-13 23:00" 
> latest_trend_names = result['trends'][ts].collect { |t| t['name'] }
> latest_trend_names.each { |tn| p tn }
"#myweddingsong"
"#mydivorcesong"
"#ThingsPeopleShouldntDo"
"I'm a Celeb"
"HEADLESS GAGA"
"CHRIS BROWN IS A LEGEND"
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but how can i do that? i'm new on this

Comment: sorry about that, now i can see the full answer. thanks a lot

Comment: @CarlosRaulAparicioHernandez It depends entirely on what you want to show. I'll add a single example to the answer; I was limiting the scope the why you were getting the exception

Comment: @CarlosRaulAparicioHernandez No problem :) Make sure to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so future visitors can also benefit from your work :)